Allow RTK-Query to retain the data for specific time period while refetching the data in the background
I'm new to React and in my project I'm using RTK-Query to retain the data after fetching it for some time. Everything is working well, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around the caching strategy. To put it simply, I want it to behave in such a way that when the hook is called after 5mins, it will return the old data first + refetching the data in the background, then re-render the component with the new data, so no loading state to be shown to the user. From what I understand, with my current configuration, it will return undefined (aka no data) 5m after last access, and refetch the data 5m after last fetch. How can I achieve this? I'm thinking of increasing the retention time to longer time, but the policy only allows 5mins so I'm a bit stuck here.
Here is my code (I omitted some parts to make it easier to understand)
const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  baseQuery: fakeBaseQuery(),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getApi: builder.query({
      queryFn: async () => {
        ...
      },
      // keep the data for 5 mins after last usage
      keepUnusedDataFor: 60 * 5,
    }),
  }),
  // allow refetch the data after 5 mins from last fetch in background
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: 60 * 5,
});

Thank you for the help

refetchOnMountOrArgChange will do what you want, but as long as you have keepUnusedDataFor set to the same value, old data will get thrown away so you always start with undefined. Set that to a higher value or remove the option.

I understand that I need to keep refetchOnMountOrArgChange, but can I ask why did you suggest to remove keepUnusedDataFor option? Won't it set the caching time to 60s instead?

Ah right - then set it to 20 minutes or something. Right now it would refetch if data in the store is older than 5 minutes, but you remove it after 5 minutes of not being used, which seems to be the problem you describe here, right?

Otoh... I'm not 100% sure if in the refetching case the data is available in that way... (And I should remember, I've written the hook ^^). You might also want to look into currentData instead of data to get it while it's still fetching. Might be worth a try.

I think so, I was asking to make sure if there's any other way to achieve this setup without having to explicitly set the retention time to longer than 5m :")  I already checked currentData and its undefined as well. I guess I will ask if I can increase the retention time, thank you ^^
